# Flutter- How to extract Retrofit api defination to separate files for cleaner code in dart

Tags: flutter, api, dart, retrofit2, clean-architecture

ApiClient.dart

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart' hide Headers;
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';

import '../../../constants/links/urls_constant.dart';
part 'api_cilent.g.dart';
part './components/auth/registration_client.dart';

@RestApi()
abstract class ApiClient {
  factory ApiClient(
    Dio dio, {
    required String baseUrl,
  }) = _ApiClient;

  @POST(KUrl.login)
  @Headers({"Accept": "application/json"})
  @Headers({"Content-type": "application/json"})
  Future<HttpResponse<dynamic>> login();
}
```

I would like to extract the below code to `registration_client.dart`

```
@POST(KUrl.login)
  @Headers({"Accept": "application/json"})
  @Headers({"Content-type": "application/json"})
  Future<HttpResponse<dynamic>> login();
```

How to do it?

I was trying with `part` and `part of` but this didn't worked for me...

```
part of '../../api_client.dart.dart';


  @POST(KUrl.login)
  @Headers({"Accept": "application/json"})
  @Headers({"Content-type": "application/json"})
  Future<HttpResponse<dynamic>> login({@Header("Authorization") required String authToken,});
```

I also tried adding this to a function and call it in `api_client` but that also didn't worked for me :/

Error I got was:

```
A function body must be provided.
Try adding a function body.dart(missing_function_body)
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The @ tags on the code means that certain code generator is going to look for that specific piece of code to generate more code. I've never tried to separate the actions (@POST, @GET, etc) away from the abstract class, but I believe you're getting that error because it's not possible...since the code generator might be looking for both on the same class. I guess u have to follow the template.